# Build failed with cstdio and cstdlib errors in visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: alglibTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 5/22/2011 12:52:26 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\alglibTest.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(38): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(40): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'using'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(40): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(40): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'using'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(41): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'clearerr'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(41): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(41): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fclose'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(41): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(41): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'feof'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(41): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(42): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ferror'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(42): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(42): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fflush'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(42): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(42): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fgetc'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(42): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(43): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fgetpos'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(43): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(43): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fgets'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(43): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(43): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fopen'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(43): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(44): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fprintf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(44): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(44): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fputc'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(44): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(44): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fputs'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(44): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(45): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fread'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(45): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(45): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'freopen'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(45): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(45): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fscanf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(45): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(46): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fseek'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(46): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(46): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fsetpos'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(46): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(46): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ftell'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(46): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(47): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fwrite'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(47): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(47): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'getc'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(47): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(47): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'getchar'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(47): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(48): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'gets'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(48): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(48): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'perror'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(48): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(49): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'putc'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(49): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(49): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'putchar'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(49): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(50): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'printf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(50): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(50): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'puts'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(50): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(50): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'remove'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(50): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(51): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'rename'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(51): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(51): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'rewind'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(51): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(51): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'scanf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(51): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(52): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'setbuf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(52): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(52): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'setvbuf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(52): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(52): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sprintf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(52): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(53): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sscanf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(53): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1    >c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(53): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tmpfile'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(53): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(53): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tmpnam'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(53): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(54): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ungetc'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(54): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(54): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'vfprintf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(54): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(54): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'vprintf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(54): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(55): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'vsprintf'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(55): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(19): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(19): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'using'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(19): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'using'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'abs'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atexit'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(21): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(22): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atof'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(22): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(22): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atoi'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(22): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(22): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atol'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(22): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(23): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'bsearch'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(23): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.57
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 28):

This usually happens when you are trying to compile C code with C++ headers. If you want to compile C code, change C++ headers to C headers (cstdio to stdio.h, cstdlib to stdlib.h), if you want to compile C++ code, change your project settings (Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As C++ code).

Comment: Headers included with the /FI compiler option can also cause this error, if a C++ header is treated as a C header.

Comment: Good lord.. thank you soo much. I've been programming over a decade and just saw this for the first time and was extremely confused. I honestly though Visual Studio was broken haha. I feel like they could do a much better job of detecting this and warning you about your typo. I included `<string>` instead of `<string.h>`.. oops.