# Compile a C library with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I got here a C library written by someone else, with a very nice way to compile it on a Mac and generate a ruby wrapper.

I am on Windows, and I need to generate a wrapper for .Net. I know absolutely nothing about C or C++.

- I have created a `.i` file that just `%include` the `.h` file, and used [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) to generate C# files and a `xxx_wrapper.c` file.
- I have created an empty C++ project with Visual Studio 2010, and included all the `.h` and `.c` files of the project (except the ones to generate the ruby wrapper)
- Now when I try to compile, I get a few compilation errors each time there is an inline function:

  `file.c(54): error C2054: '(' expected after 'inline'`
  `file.c(54): error C2085: 'swap_img' : is not in the formal parameters list`
  `file.c(54): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'`

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6086702/2354542) that it might be because VS tries to compile my c files as c++. But how do I do that ? I can't change anything in the code (and I wouldn't try), so I just need to "fix" the project.

Thanks !

Comment: If your file names end in `.c` then VS will compile them as C, not C++.

Comment: Could you please translate the error messages? Not everyone speaks Surrender.

Comment: @librik: ok, but if so, why doesn't my pristine project compile them ?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: yes sorry I've translated them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the version of the C language that's supported by Visual Studio 2010, there is no word `inline`.  Only C++ has `inline`.  I don't think `inline` became a part of C until the very latest version of the C standard (C11), which nobody supports yet.

Instead, you should use the word `__inline`, which means the same thing.  The underscores imply that this is an "extension," something that's not part of standard C.

Alternatively, you could put `#define inline __inline` at the start of each file, or in a `.h` header file which is `#include`d at the beginning.  That would automatically translate the word `inline` to `__inline` each time it appears.

(It's likely that the person who wrote that code was using a different compiler, one which chose to add `inline` without the underscores.  It's still an "extension" because it's not part of Standard C.)

Comment: ok so if I add the underscores, will it still compile in the other's compiler ? (I think it's make but I don't know which version)

Comment: If the other compiler is GCC, then yes.  But the trouble with extensions is that they're not "portable," meaning there's no guarantee they'll work everywhere.  You could surround the `#define inline __inline` with `#ifdef _MSC_VER` ... `#endif` to ensure that the `__inline` only applies to Microsoft C.

Comment: The reason for those specific error messages is that it thinks you want `inline` to be the name of the function.  (Since it doesn't know the word as part of C.)  So it says things like "expected a ( after inline" -- when you're writing a function you put a ( after the name.

Comment: Thanks ! I have another error now, but this one is gone ! :)